# I want to sent large video in server What to Use AsyncTask Or a Service?

Tags: java, android, service, android-asynctask

**im new in android and maybe im doing stupid questions i have make my first app,
it will record video and sent to server and the video is with small size or large size (depend in the client) i have test with AsyncTask and work but i what to know maybe is more good to use service i mean is more security for me that the app will work in all device and sent the video because when i have testet ,in some device the app crash and in some device not 
Any Answer will Help me a lot Thank You**

Comment: You should think about formatting your questions properly, adding some code and proofread your question before you send it.

Comment: i dont have any problem with my code i just ask how is the best way to sent the video to server using AsynkTask or using the Service ?

Comment: Use a service is best thing for upload larger files in android.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer